# Unable to sweep account using WIF, Green wallet says "No UTXO found"

Tags: development

I am trying to learn the process BTC transactions.
In the process, I generated

- Private key : **82e8034869c77744655899d450f9fe2f01fad030bf8af4ea75b310d1a140f554**
- Corresponding address generated : **2MwVArnwmXQokkhn61Dgi68LnxBEuM1SrxN**
- WIF : **93NdjSVUcd172o55kErspBPn8jARKq4veeb3pVZyoTSa49bqnpU**
- Transaction : https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/tx/8c8140845faef14f860147fcd774355af665098c89cd35b59efee5c8efef3b66/

When I try to sweep using the WIF into Green Wallet by BlockStream, it says No UTXO found. Help me understand what exactly am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure you are using a compressed public key when generating 2MwVArnwmXQokkhn61Dgi68LnxBEuM1SrxN?

Answer (score 1):

That WIF private key does not correspond to that address. Not even if you convert the key to its uncompressed format.

That hex private key does not correspond to either the address or the WIF private key.